# HttpSession remains after server restart

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, httpsession

I'm learning Spring. Doing the login/logout functionality. 
This is what my controller looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/successfulLoginAuth", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView postHttpLogin(HttpSession session, Authentication authInfo) 
{

ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
mav.setViewName("redirect:/index.html");
session.setAttribute("authInfo", authInfo);

return mav;

}
```

The log in is performed via Spring Security using a dao service which I have implemented. That works fine.

This is the content of index.jsp:

```
<% 
    HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(false);
    Authentication authInfo; 
    if( (session1 != null) && 
        ( (authInfo = (Authentication)session1.getAttribute("authInfo")) != null) 
      )
    {

        out.print(" yo " + authInfo.getName() + " " + authInfo.getAuthorities().iterator().next().getAuthority());
    }
    else
    {
%>    
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/registration">New? Sign Up!</a><br/>

<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">Existing? Sign In!</a><br/>
<%} %>
```

When i log in, and restart the server, I'm still logged in. Shouldn't the session information be lost after a server restart? If i restart the browser, it works as it should (ie the session info is lost).

This is my Spring Security configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/successfulLoginAuth" authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService"></authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `Tomcat`, which uses a Manager component to persist sessions between application life-cycles. You can change all those settings in [the Manager component configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html).

I *think* it also depends on the kind of changes you do. Eclipse's plugin for Tomcat server will decide if it should flush the serialized `HttpSession`s or not.

Comment: Thanks! This is a server config thing. Under context.xml i saw this line and made the change:  Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts:
    `<Manager pathname="" />`

Comment: If you're wondering why your Tomcat does this and never set it up, look for a file named SESSIONS.ser somewhere in your temp directory - Tomcat saves this file as part of a correct shutdown procedure.

Answer (score 8):

I am guessing you are using Tomcat,

From the Docs SaveOnRestart property

```
Should all sessions be persisted and reloaded when Tomcat is shut down and restarted (or when this application is reloaded)? By default, this attribute is set to true.
```

You can control this by changing the property to false in your context.xml

```
<Manager pathname="">
      <saveOnRestart>false</saveOnRestart>
</Manager>
```